# tf.scatter_nd_update keeps giving me an AttributeError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm on TF V1.15.

I followed the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update). This is my code:

```
# v is a tensor of shape [15360].
num = 15360
sz = 7680  
ind = np.random.randint(num, size = sz)
ind = tf.constant(ind)
upd = tf.constant(0., shape=[sz])
v_ = tf.scatter_nd_update(v, ind, upd)
```

And I keep getting the error:

```
v_ = tf.scatter_nd_update(v, ind, upd)
File "/root/anaconda/envs/../lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 366, in scatter_nd_update
return ref._lazy_read(gen_state_ops.resource_scatter_nd_update(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read'
```

I tried wrapping `upd` and `ind` as `tf.Variable` looking at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21957) issue but I get the same error.

Comment: But from the docs that you've mentioned, the syntax would be `tensor_scatter_nd_update`. Or try to use `tf.compat.v1.scatter_nd_update` instead.

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar I tried using that just now, I get the same error

Comment: Is `v` a tf.variable or a tf.tensor?

Comment: It's a `tf.tensor` @thushv89

Comment: No, you couldn't. Since only `tf.Variable` which has `scatter_nd_update`.

Comment: Thanks! That's right, I had to wrap `v` as `tf.Variable` and not `ind` and `upd`.